# How to get OrderID to add new lines to the Order In SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

So I'm certain the answer is online, but I can't really find it. Googling gets me all sort of unrelated topics when I search things like "sql add lines to existing order" etc.

I am using C# and ASP.NET with SQL Server to store an order when a customer buys something to form an order history. I am doing all of the necessary steps and have my database organized with two tables

Order will have OrderID (primary key), UserID (foreign key), ect. and then OrderLines

OrderLines will have LineID (primary key), OrderID (foreign key), ProductID (foreign key) ect.

My question is, how do I insert this whole order into SQL?

Right now I have a method that will create a SQL query to INSERT INTO database order table and it will have no OrderLines.

so INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order] etc. etc.

Then I want to add OrderLines from my List. How do I get that OrderID so that I can put it into the database? I can't query the db for what I just put in because I don't have search parameters and "Grabbing the last entry" seems to be error-prone.

INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrderLines] except I don't know how to grab OrderID.

Sorry if this is badly phrased.

EDIT:

My Code

```
bool AddOrder(order parameters)
    InsertOrder method
    for(int k=0;k<amount of Lines; k++) 
        InsertLine(orderID, line)

InsertOrder
    ExecuteString("INSERT INTO STUFF")

InsertLine
    ExecuteString("INSERT INTO STUFF")
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the identity of the last inserted record.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{
    int orderID;    
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (Created,OrderTotal) VALUES (GetDate(),@OrderTotal); SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY()) as OrderID;", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderTotal", 10.0f);
        connection.Open();
        orderID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    //... now you can use orderID in your next query to insert an OrderLine
}
```

Comment: The problem is the hierarchy of my code. I have three different methods. I'll edit my problem up top.

Comment: right so your InsertOrder method should look like I show above, and should simply return orderID. Then it can be used in your for loop there as a parameter to InsertLine

Comment: oh duh, I was so deadset on it being a bool I didn't even think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) for MS-SQL or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for MySQL (not sure which one you're after) and select that out in the result of your SQL query.

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order] -- etc etc

 -- ... other lines here

 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- or LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

This will return the identity of what you just inserted. Then, in C#, you can use `ExecuteScalar` of your `SqlCommand` and cast the result to an `int`:

```
var orderId = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```